# Как обрезать блок по заданной форме

Tags: html, css, svg, inkscape

Есть такой дизайн.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внизу блока вместо прямой границы нарисован овал. Как его сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вам не нужно, реализовывать слайдер, а достаточно добавить подобного рода статический блок, то просто вырежьте картинку и сохраните в формате png, а после добавьте в качестве фона. Если же необходимо, чтобы слайдер работал, то можете с помощью `position: absolute;` наложить сверху белое изображение закругленной формы

Comment: Я так и думал. Думал что есть решение с помощью SVG. Если так не сделать то сделаю как вы сказали.

Answer (score 12):

Картинку можно обрезать по криволинейной форме с помощью `clip-path` или `mask` или `pattern`.

Но во всех случаях нужен `path` для криволинейной формы.

- Для того, чтобы получить этот криволинейный `<path>` необходимо
  загрузить картинку в векторный редактор и нанести узловые точки с
  помощью инструмента, - `Рисовать кривые Безье` (1. на рисунке)
- Изменить тип узлов на `автоматически сглаженные` цифра 3 на рисунке и
  передвигая, уменьшая или увеличивая длину рычагов (4), добиться полного
  совпадения кривой с заданной формой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохранить файл в формате `SVG`
  Оптимизировать файл (будет убрана лишняя информация Inkscape) с помощью [SVG-EDITOR](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)
- Скопировать формулу `path`

Далее будем использовать этот `<path>` для обрезки изображения по заданной форме

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#7AA3A3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 674 236"  >   
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="cp1">
  <path d="m0 0.6 674 0v155c0 0-22.3 24.9-35.8 34.5-12.8 9-27.2 15.8-42 20.9-18.8 6.4-38.7 10-58.5 11.7-21.8 1.9-43.8-0.1-65.7-1.7-30.3-2.3-60.3-7.5-90.4-11.5-26.3-3.5-52.7-6.8-78.9-10.8C232.2 187.7 91.8 162.5 91.8 162.5L0 146.3Z" style="fill:none;stroke:black"/> 
  </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9db1R.png" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#cp1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Приложение полностью адаптивно и работает во всех браузерах**

Comment: Не работает в IE. Вытягивает вниз изображение.

Comment: @Denis что у вас не работает? Ваш пример или моё решение. Проверил, - всё работает.

Comment: В IE11 изображение вытягивается по высоте.