# Как на css написать горбик?

Tags: css, css3

Есть блок, хочу сделать плавный переход на белый цвет.
1 вариант - `svg` - не шарю, и не хочу кешировать, с `png` такая же история.
Попытки создать на css - обламались.

[image: картинка]

Comment: @L.F.C. не через `svg` и не через `png`.

Comment: `canvas` тоже в топку?

Comment: @L.F.C, если у вас есть решение на `canvas`- буду рад увидеть.
Вот что у меня получалось на `css` - https://i.imgur.com/TJApgd0.png . И то, через костыли...

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/957314/262779

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only CSS будет как-то так:

```css
.up,
.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.up {
  top: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9));
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 20% 180% 0 0/200% 200% 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3));
}

body { background-color: #00bcd4; background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'); }
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```